# Laravel one way communication

Tags: php, laravel-5, kurento

I want laravel backend to send a message to my Ionic App whenever there is an entry in my database. I don't want to do polling at frontend, found this library **rukavina/kurento-client-php**
 (*https://github.com/rukavina/kurento-client-php*) but unable to get any success as I was getting this error.

```
Array ( 
  [code] => 40201 
  [data] => Array ( 
    [type] => SDP_PARSE_ERROR 
  )
  [message] => Empty offer not valid
)
```

Can anyone help me who either implemented kurento-client-php library or worked on similar situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally did it using Laravel-ratchet and php-zmq.